# List of figures in bookdown to html_document2

Tags: r, reference, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

Is there any possibility to include a list of figures in my Rmd-Document?
Right now my yaml-header looks like this, but I have no clue of how to include a list of figures.
The `\figureslift` doesn't seem to work.

```
---
title: ""
author: ""
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    #css: styles.css
    fig_caption: yes
    theme: flatly
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 1
bibliography: lib.bib
link-citations: yes
figurelist: yes
---
```

And in the body file I thought about something like this to produce a list of figures.

```
{r figure1, fig.cap="Sine Plot", fig.align='center'}
x = seq(1,10, by = 0.1)
y = sin(x)
plot(x, y, main = "title")
```

See figure @ref(fig:figure1)

\listoffigures

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that also shows how you include your figures?

Comment: I tried to add a minimal example:) It's acutally just about producing plots in R, referencing them and then in the end creating a list of figures

Answer (score 6):

In principle you could add `lof: yes` to your YAML header. However, according to the [pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), these parameters are only supported for the LaTeX and ConTeXt backends. Consequently, this would work for `bookdown::pdf_document2`, which uses LaTeX, but not for `bookdown::html_docuemnt2`.

There is a [request](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1965) in pandoc's issue tracker to add LoF/LoT/... support for other backends as well. However, it seems nobody has taken that (rather complex) task up.